# Integrating Request tracker with angular 2

Tags: rest, api, angular, angular2-forms

I am trying to Integrate Request Tracker in my angular 2 web app for form submission using REST api provided by RT here is link 
(https://rt-wiki.bestpractical.com/wiki/REST#Ticket_Create)
But i when I am trying to do a post it gives me preflight response failed error. I am using local storage (html5) to save user details and pass them during post. 
I dont have access to physical Request Tracker only the API 
any ideas how can i solve CORS problem.

Second question is when i try to create a ticket through post man it gives error 
id and queue required I have tried passing them as body as well as parameter didn't helped

Comment: did you find any solution for this?